# How to prevent repeating data in JasperReports TextField

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *JasperReports* and have some problem with textField data continue on next page.
I have 3 textField in detail band.
Band splitType="Stretch".
Every textfiled has borders and isPrintWhenDetailOverflows param set "true".
When data in textfield does not fit on page it continues on next. So i need to print other textfileds of same band (because i need to print borders of every textfield)
But isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true also leads to repeating data in other textfields on second page though their contents fits on first page.

Illustration:

[image]

Comment: Have you set `isStretchWithOverflow="true"` for `textField`? What is the value of `stretchType` attribute of `reportElement` inside `textField`?

Comment: Please provide the jrxml code of your textfields.

Comment: <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement style="cell" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="266" y="0" width="266" height="15"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
            <font fontName="Arial" size="9" isBold="false" pdfEncoding="Cp1251" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            <paragraph leftIndent="2"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{structure}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jasper report documentation says:

```
isPrintWhenDetailOverflows()
If this is set to true, the element will be reprinted on the next page if the band does not fit in the current page.
```

So I think it might be a problem. **Remove** `isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"`. The two things **`isStretchWithOverflow="true"`** and **`stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"`** are working for me in this case. So your `textField` will be like:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
   <reportElement style="cell" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="266" y="0" width="266" height="15"/>
   <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
     <font fontName="Arial" size="9" isBold="false" pdfEncoding="Cp1251" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
     <paragraph leftIndent="2"/>
   </textElement>
   <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{structure}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: neither stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" no stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" don't solve the problem

Comment: As I can see in the image, `textfield1` and `textfield3` contents are not getting repeated on second page. Isn't that what you want? About the border, it will enclose the text only since textField is already stretched beyond it's predefined height. I don't think you can get border on second page too for `textfield1` and `textfield3`