# iReport 4.5.0 duplicating last row of a page when the text is to large

Tags: jasper-reports

When the text overflows de cell that he should be in, the line appears duplicated on the next page. The picture illustrate the error:

[image: Error on iReport 4.5.0]

The line information presented on the last line of the first page (number 1) is the same that is presented on the first line of the second page (number 2). The text presented on number 3 should be "SEPTOPLASTIA POR VIDEOENDOSCOPIA". The text broke into two parts (number 3 and 4).

Anyone knows if theres a config for this?

Comment: Anyone? This is a huge problem for my report...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent repeating data in JasperReports TextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202593/how-to-prevent-repeating-data-in-jasperreports-textfield) & [Avoid split of text field to multiple pages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10744920/876298)